# OrderBy using RavenDB-an exception

Tags: linq, ravendb

I use Raven Db in my project. Im trying to order list like below:

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => x.Supporters.Sum(y=>y.Tokens));
```

And i got an exception like this:

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'."}
```

Model looks as below:

```
public class Idea 
{

    (...)
    public IList<IdeaSupporter> Supporters { get; set; }

}

public class IdeaSupporter
{
   (...)
    public int Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

What do i wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort on a computation, but you can define an index like this:

```
from idea in docs.Ideas
select new 
{
  SumOfSupportersTokens = idea.Supporters.Sum(x=>x.Tokens)
}
```

And then sort on SumOfSupportersTokens